# How to make the server listen on any port?

Tags: java, client-server

I'm implementing a basic Client-Server program in java. I read that 0 as the port number can be used to in the ServerSocket constructor to listen on any port. But my following code throws exceptions.

Main Function for Server

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(0);
        Socket socket=s.accept();


    }
```

Main Function for client

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket socket=new Socket("127.0.0.1",1024);
        System.out.println(socket.getPort());


    }
```

Comment: Why are you providing a port on the specific client to connect to if your server does not accept on a specific port?

Comment: Not *any* port. Just a dynamically-assigned one, rather than one explictly set by the program.

Comment: No. "A port number of 0 means that the port number is automatically allocated, typically from an ephemeral port range. This port number can then be retrieved by calling getLocalPort." (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int%29)